# How to Minify the HTML Response in Google App Engine

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-app-engine

I have a spring boot application & hosted on Google App Engine. Its working fine.
I have tried to minify the html response. Minify worked in my local pc with Tomcat.

But minify not working in Google App Engine.

### pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.htmlcompressor</groupId>
    <artifactId>htmlcompressor</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.yahoo.platform.yui</groupId>
    <artifactId>yuicompressor</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.8</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>js</artifactId>
            <groupId>rhino</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

### Filter.java

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    PrintWriter outWriter;
    try {
        CharResponseWrapper responseWrapper = new CharResponseWrapper((HttpServletResponse) response);
        chain.doFilter(request, responseWrapper);
        String servletResponse = responseWrapper.toString();
        if (servletResponse != null && !servletResponse.equals("")) {
            outWriter = httpResponse.getWriter();
            outWriter.write(compressor.compress(servletResponse));
            outWriter.flush();
            outWriter.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }
}
```

### CharResponseWrapper.java

```
package com.app.filter;

import java.io.CharArrayWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper;

public class CharResponseWrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper 
{
    private final CharArrayWriter output;

    public CharResponseWrapper(HttpServletResponse response)
    {
        super(response);
        output = new CharArrayWriter();
    }

    @Override
    public PrintWriter getWriter() 
    {
        return new PrintWriter(output);
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() 
    {
        return output.toString();
    }    
}
```

In Google App Engine

```
CharResponseWrapper responseWrapper = new CharResponseWrapper((HttpServletResponse) response);
```

**responseWrapper**  is **null**;

Answer (score 0):

You can try to write a deploy script that makes a copy of your code with minified HTML, and then call it on at deployment.